# Need to use both client and server side certificates in JMeter to hit a POST request for SSL Connection

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, load-testing, keystore

I have a scenario where I need to hit a POST Request in JMEter with Server side certificate (certificate.ca.crt) and Client side certificates with (client.pem and private.key) for SSL Connection.

I have configured these certificates with POSTMAN and it's working fine but in JMeter I am new and I don't know how to do it?

I have done one thing so far in JMeter after some research. I have executed following command to make a .p12 format file

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificates.p12 -inkey private.key -in certificate.ca.crt -in client.pem
```

and then I placed the certificates.p12 under bin directory of JMeter and added following properties in system.properties on JMeter's bin directory

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificates.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password

https.keyStoreStartIndex=0
https.keyStoreEndIndex=1
```

After doing this when I execute my API from JMeter, I am getting following error,

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create keystore: pkcs12     not found
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.createContext(JsseSSLManager.java:214)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.getContext(JsseSSLManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:113)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:850)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:561)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1271)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: pkcs12     not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.keystore.JmeterKeyStore.<init>(JmeterKeyStore.java:85)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.keystore.JmeterKeyStore.getInstance(JmeterKeyStore.java:255)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:122)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: pkcs12     KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 30 more
```

Looking forward to your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a number of whitespaces after `pkcs12` so it is rather `pkcs12`

If you remove trailing whitespaces it should work normally.

I also believe that it's not mandatory to specify this `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` property as [JMeter will guess it from the file name](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/SSLManager.java#L125) and the functionality [is there for years](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52131)

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

With regards to server-side certificates you [don't have to do anything at all](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl)

> The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc. This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working for me with your solution. whitespaces after `pkcs12` was the problem inside my system.properties file. so it was rather `pkcs12     `